# Approximation of $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-bx^2}sin(ax^2)dx$ when a>>b

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, approximation

This is from an exercise in Migdal's "Qualitative Methods in Quantum Theory".

For the case for where b>>a, we can arrive at an estimate by re-writing the integral in the following way:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-z^2}sin(\frac{a}{b}z^2)dz \approx \frac{a}{b^{3/2}}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-z^2}z^2dz = a\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{16b^3}}.
$$

However, I have been stuck trying to show that in the case a>>b, the integral is approximately $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8a}}$. I am currently unsure how to treat the sine term, which oscillates quite fast. I considered approximating the integral's value by just considering the first half-cycle of an oscillation, but that didn't seem to bring me any closer to the known estimate.

Any hints/idea what approximations may be used to recover the given estimate when a>>b?

Comment: It's not the same flavor of approximation used for the case $b \gg a$ in the question statement, but n.b. we can evaluate this integral in closed form in terms of elementary functions,
$$\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2 \sqrt[4]{a^2 + b^2}} \sin \left(\frac 12 \arctan \frac ab\right),$$ and using that when $a \gg b$ we have $\sin (\cdots) \approx \sin \frac\pi4 = \frac1{\sqrt2}$ and $\sqrt[4]{a^2 + b^2} \approx \sqrt a$ immediately gives the desired estimate.

Comment: @TravisWillse Thanks for your answer! Is there a way of arriving at the estimate with no prior knowledge of the closed form expression?

Comment: Making the turn in the complex plane (integrating along the line $x=te^{\frac{\pi i}4}$), for $a\gg b$ 
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-bx^2}\sin(ax^2)dx=\Im\int_0^\infty e^{-bx^2}e^{iax^2}dx\overset{x=e^{\pi i/4}t}{=}\Im\,e^{\frac{\pi i}4}\int_0^\infty e^{-at^2-ibt^2}dt\to\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\sqrt2\,\sqrt a}$$
given tha fact that the integral along the arch $Re^{i\phi}; \phi\in[0;\frac{\pi i}4]$ tends to zero as $R\to\infty$, and there is no poles inside the segment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Euler representation of the sine function, the antiderivative is an error function since
$$\int e^{-bx^2}\,\sin(ax^2)\,dx=\Im \left( \int e^{ (b-i a)x^2}\,dx\right)$$

As @Travis Willse already wrote in comments
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-bx^2}\,\sin(ax^2)\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2 \sqrt[4]{a^2+b^2}}\,\sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\right)$$

Let $a=k b$ and Taylor expand for large values of $k$

$$I=\frac 1 2 \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2 b k} }\left(1-\frac{1}{2 k}-\frac{3}{8
   k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)\right)$$ Replace $k$ by $\frac a b$

Comment: In fact the explicit form is an algebraic an algebraic expression in $a, b$:
$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi\left(\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} - b\right)}{8 (a^2 + b^2)}}$$.